# Expander IsExpanded binding to listbox selected

Tags: wpf, binding, listbox, expander

So I have a `Listbox` whose items contain an `Expander`. What I am trying to do is bind the `IsExpanded` property to the `IsSelected` property of the parent `ListBoxItem`. The whole purpose is that if they selected a different listbox item it'll collapse the current selected item and expand the new slected item.

**UPDATE (CODE):**

```
<ListBox SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <Boreder BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"
                      BorderBrush="Black">
                 <Expander IsExpanded={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem},
                                               Path=IsSelected} />
             </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: We'll need some code

Comment: @nkoniishvt I have added some code. It does not work because I cannot bind to the IsSelected part of the ListBoxItem. I'm looking for something like that though. If the item is selected then the expander should be selected. Since it is set as `SelectionMode="Single"` then only one item should be selected/expanded at any moment.

Answer (score 3):

The property/binding I was looking for was `IsExpanded="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem, Mode=FindAncestor}}"`